# Runner class is not able to pick up the Step defintion file

Tags: cucumber, runner

[My Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWB2p.png)

Hi, I am new to Cucumber and trying to create a dummy project for practice.
As you can see in the project structure I have created step definition file(MenuTest) in com.netreveal.testcases package, but when trying to run it by the Runner class which is in com.netreveal.login package it gives me below errors.Though, when I keep my MenuTest in com.netreveal.login package it runs fine? [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU7w1.png)[Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeJAt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the Runner class so that the glue matches the package name of the steps definitions classes:

```
glue = { "com.netreveal.testcases" }
```

The features path can also be relative and point at the entire folder or specific feature file if preferred:

```
features = { "src/main/resources/NetReveal/testcases" }
```